# How to take value from a dynamic element angular2

Tags: typescript

**HTML:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
      <td #id>{{item.id}}</td>         
      <td>{{item.comment}}</td>
      <td> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"  (click)="deleteTime(id.value)"></i></td>
    </tr>
```

**DeleteTime method in the component:**

```
deleteTime(id_value) {
let id = id_value;
var arg= {
  "id": id
};

this.myService.deleteTime(arg).subscribe();
  }
```

Successfully I am creating my html elements and when the user clicks the image the deleteTime button click event is activating, but id.value is undefined, so I cannot delete the item. The problem is in that I am not taking the value of the **#id td** properly. I tried with passing the clickevent {{item.id}}, but  then I encountered syntax error.

Comment: `id.value` is not defined. Do you means `item.id` or `item.id.value` ?

Comment: @Doomenik, id.value is not defined. I managed to find a workaround way, which I posted as an answer. I don't know if there is a cleaner way of doing it

Comment: inside of the id Element is only item.id stored so why not simply: `deleteTime(item.id)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
  <td #id>{{item.id}}</td>         
  <td>{{item.comment}}</td>
  <td> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"  (click)="deleteTime(id)"></i></td>
</tr>

deleteTime(idElement:HTMLElement) {
let id = idElement.InnerText;
var arg= {
 "id": id
};

this.myService.deleteTime(arg).subscribe();
}
```

Instead of trying to pass the value, I passed the HTML Element and took it's innerText.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say this was very bad approach. Use id  from item instead of using innerHTML. `deleteItem(item.id)` and that's it

And you do not need this

```
let id = idElement.InnerText;
var arg= {
 "id": id
};
```